# 1 million bio-metric (small) File Comparison Using Hadoop/HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop2, hdf

i am a beginner to the hadoop , read smallfile problem in hadoop,now  i have a problem to be solved in , help me to get started

**Problem :**

*Source Outcome :* Around 1 million+ (approx) files each having nearly 1 kb size (Cannot be prevented from creating or regulating size)

*Outcome Grouping:*
Source Outcome are Grouped into 1000 Files A Group .

**Task Needed:**

Files with in a group are to be compared in a one-to-one manner
Files are binary minutia (bio-metric) files following a particular standard structure (Header,content...etc)

As the Source Outcome are expected to increase in the time , i would like to implement the comparison on hadoop

**Input to the Hadoop:**

< InputFile > < HARFile > < Output >

**< InputFile Sample >:**

Note that File names are unique ids and emit the file name alone  can help a lot

```
            08RTC345744.txt 08RTC345746.txt
            08RTC345744.txt 08RTC3457XX.txt
            08RTXX457XX.txt 08YYC3457YY.txt
            ..................
             XXXXXXN.txt YYYYYYN.txt
```

**Process Algorithm:** (its not implemented ,but just an idea )

> 1. Read input file line by line
> 2. Read Each file    in the line with thehelp of har:// (eg: Read har://xxx/08RTC345744.txt and har://xxx/08RTC345746.txt )
> 3. Compare theFile that are read from hdfs (HAR) using a relevant bio-metric algorithm
> 4. if they shows     similarity Emit < Filenames > < Count >

**< HARFile SAMPLE Files >**

```
08RTC345744.txt 
08RTC345746.txt
08RTC345745.txt 
08RTC3457XX.txt
08RTXX457XB.txt 
08YYC3457YY.txt
```

1) Is it a better   idea to implement in Hadoop ?

2)I read that   comparing small files is a problem in hadoop , is it Better to form a   HAR File for a Set of groups then compare ?

3) Will my  **Process Algorithm:** Works or Not ?

4) is efficient ?  i think, Surely not ,any other idea ?

5) Any idea regarding MapReduce on a bio-metric matching ?

6)Is HBASE a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of data you have is at a border line to be viable for processing in hadoop cluster. A small cluster would be suffice unless you will have much more files comming in.

The first problem you have here is ingestion of your data into the cluster. You have lots of small files that each contain one data record, if I undestood correctly. What you want to end up with are fewer larger files. To solve this problem I would merge the files before or at the moment of ingestion. HAR files are not a good option. There are number of ways you can do that and it mainly depends on how will your data be arriving to your cluster and how you will be processing it later. You can check out. 
If your data comes in as an unbounded stream check out:
 - Apache Flume
 - Apache Kafka
 - Apache Storm
 - Apache Spark
If your data is already somewhere and you're doing a one time job:
 - Implement your own program that does the merging.

The common thing here is that you want to represent each one of your files as one data record. Then you can decide on the file format you want to store many records with. By properly configuring above tools you will end up with large files on your HDFS containing data records.

Then you need to decide how you want to process the data. You want to compare records to one another and for that you can use a number of tools also:

- Plain MapReduce. Implement everything with low level tools. Check out on how to make cross join efficiently since that's what you're doing.
- Hive. Implement an UDF that invokes your comparison algorithm and express the whole job as an SQL query.
- Pig. Similar to hive but with it's own scripting language.
- Apache Spark. Newer tool with a nice API, capable of implementing the job like with MapReduce but in a much easier and cleaner way.

What to use will ultimately depend on your use case and your available environment.